# Add missing numbers in a list of integers sorted in ascending order

Tags: python, list

I am trying to implement a function that would insert any missing numbers in a list. The list is in ascending order with no repetitive elements.

This is my code so far:

```
def fill_in_numbers(lst):
    i=0
    while True:
        if lst[-1] - lst[i] !=1:
            lst.insert(i+1, lst[i]+1)
        i+=1
        if lst[-1] - lst[i]== 1:
            break
    return lst
```

So, for example, if the input is `fill_in_numbers([12,15,19])` the expected output is `[12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]`, or if the input is `fill_in_numbers([-5,0,5])` the expected output is `[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]`.

However, when I run my code the output I get for the first input is `[12,13,14,15,16,17,18,15,19]` and for the second one is `[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,0,5]`.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `range(lst[0], lst[-1])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers give you the solution but do not explain why yours is not working. The problem you are having is that every time you loop (until you break), you are inserting a number into your list, without checking if that number is already in the list. This results in all other original list entries that are not an extremity being pushed all the way to the end of the list.

If you desire to use your original code, than the fix should be simply in the first condition:

```
def fill_in_numbers(lst):
    i=0
    while True:
        if lst[i+1] != lst[i] + 1:
             lst.insert(i+1, lst[i]+1)
        i+=1
        if lst[-1] - lst[i]== 1:
            break
    return lst
```

If the next lst element is indeed the sequential number, then the body of the first if statement is not executed, and the 'i' iterator is incremented, allowing the next loop to use this original number in the conditions and not an unnecessary duplicate.

This is not the cleanest python code, but not too bad for just starting :)

Comment: I believe that your `lst[i+1] != lst[i] + 1` should *replace* the `lst[-1] - lst[i] !=1` in the original test, not be `and`-ed with it, because the original test doesn't serve a useful purpose here (provided that the input complies with the stated constraints).

Comment: Specifically, the only way that an item could be one less than the *last* item while not also being one less than the *next* item is if there are intervening items. But then the difference between the item and the last item would have to be at least 2 (if the list is strictly increasing and there is at least one intervening item between them), so it cannot arise that it is equal to 1. So the test is unnecessary and should be removed. In other words, the only change needed to @Python_learner's code is to compare with the next item instead of the last one, not to add an extra test.

Comment: @alani You are absolutely correct, and yes, it is good to highlight that this all works given the OP's constraints. Thank you. Answer has been updated to reflect your input.

Answer (score 2):

Take the first and last values (or min and max), throw all the old values away, and fill in new values using `range`:

```
>>> def fill_in_numbers(lst):
...     #n1 = min(lst)
...     n1 = lst[0]
...     #n2 = max(lst)
...     n2 = lst[-1]
...     lst[:] = range(n1, n2 + 1)
...     return lst
...

>>> fill_in_numbers([3, 8 , 12])
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: I should have addressed the problem with *your* solution, however.

Comment: nah I think the while loop is not relevant in this case so its my fault

Answer (score 1):

Without any complexity you can do in this way,

```
 def fill_in_numbers(lst):
        i=0
        lst = [a for a in range(lst[i],lst[-1]+1)]
    
        return lst
    
  print(fill_in_numbers([12,15,19]))
```

Comment: Of course, this returns a *new* list rather than updating the passed list and that's quite a different thing and really not what was wanted. But if you were to do this, then rather than use a list comprehension as you are doing, why not just `return list(range(lst[0],lst[-1]+1))`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect because when you insert a number into the list, you do not check if the number is already in the list.

I think the easiest way is to make a new list with [range function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) and unpack it to a list.

```
def fill_in_numbers(lst):
    return [*range(lst[0], lst[-1]+1)]
```

or

```
def fill_in_numbers(lst):
    start = lst[0]
    end = lst[-1]
    return [*range(start, end + 1)]
```

Example:

```
print(fill_in_numbers([12, 15, 19])) # Output: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
print(fill_in_numbers([-5, 0, 5])) # Output: [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Why not just the more straightforward `return list(range(lst[0], lst[-1]+1))`? However, I believe the OP wanted the original, passed list to be updated rather than a new list returned.

Answer (score 1):

**As per your logic, you need to insert number in list if number is not present in list otherwise no need to insert number in list**

```
def fill_in_numbers(lst):
    i=0
    while True:
        if lst[-1] - lst[i] !=1:
            if lst[i]+1 not in lst:
                lst.insert(i+1, lst[i]+1)
        i+=1
        if lst[-1] - lst[i]== 1:
            break
    return lst
```

**Simple Approach**

```
def fill_in_numbers(lst):
    return list(range(lst[0], lst[-1]+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this approach :

```
def fill_in_numbers(lst):
  new_list = []
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    new_list.append(lst[i])
    if i+1 < len(lst):
      [new_list.append(k) for k in range(lst[i]+1, lst[i+1])]
  return new_list


print(fill_in_numbers([12,15,19])) # --- Output --->>> [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 
print(fill_in_numbers([ -5,0, 5])) # --- Output --->>> [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The only change to the code shown in the question that is actually necessary is in the line:

```
        if lst[-1] - lst[i] !=1:
```

you need to change the `-1` to `i+1`, because you are comparing the list item with the *next* one, rather than the last one.

With that change, you get the desired result, given inputs that comply with the constraints.

---

Also you might want to consider getting rid of the `return lst` statement (the function will then return `None`).  Generally, it is advisable that the function should *either* modify the existing list *or* return a new list, but it is better not to both modify the existing list and also return it, because it can create confusion about how to use the function.  In this case, you are modifying the existing list.  So after removing the `return` statement, then when you call it you might do:

```
lst = [12,15,19]
fill_in_numbers(lst)
print(lst)
```